# what is the type of response is this?

Tags: python

I got response like this .. 7\x00E\x00Y\x00u\x00\x97\x00\xb2\x00\xb9\x00\xac\x00\x98\x00\x87\x00x\x00[\x00(\x00\xf0\xff\xd8\xff\xfd\xffX\x00\xbb\x00\xf8\x00\x04\x01\xf8\x00\xf2\x00\xf8\x00\xf9\x00\xe7\x00\xc4\x00\x99\x00i\x007\x00\t\x00\xea\xff\xdb\xff\xd6\xff\xd0\xff\xca\xff\xca\xff\xd6\xff\xe9\xff\xfa\xff\x04\x00\x05\x00\x06\x00\x0b\x00\x12\x00\x15\x00\x12\x00\x0b\x00\x06\x00\x06\x00\x07\x00\n\x00\x10\x00\x16\x00\x1a\x00\x1a\x00\x18\x00\x16\x00\x12\x00\t\x00\xfe\xff\xf7\xff\xfb\xff\x08\x00\x1a\x00(\x000\x008\x00F\x00X\x00a\x00X\x00E\x008\x002\x00(\x00\x12\x00\xf7\xff\xe5\xff\xd9\xff\xc5\xff\xa7\xff\x93\xff\x99\xff\xaa\xff\xa8\xff\x91\xff\x87\xff\x9f\xff\xba\xff\xb1\xff\x96\xff\xa5\xff\xeb\xff\x15\x00\xc4\xff\x17\xff\xac\xfe\t\xff\x15\x005\x01\xea\x01,\x02.\x02\x05\x02\x98\x01\xe4\x00\x19\x00v\xff\x17\xff\xf6\xfe\t\xffK\xff\xa7\xff\xfb\xff)\x00&\x00\xf8\xff\xa8\xffG\xff\xf6\xfe\xda\xfe\t\xff\x85\xff@\x00\x1c\x01\xf0\x01\x8c\x02\xc1\x02u\x02\xa6\x01s\x00\x17\xff\xd5\xfd\xe6\xfck\xfcy\xfc\x15\xfd'\xfet\xff\xb2\x00\xac\x01C\x02m\x02(\x02\x8a\x01\xc6\x00\x17\x00\xa3\xffy\xff\x91\xff\xd8\xff(\x00X\x00M\x00\t\x00\x9b\xff\x17\xff\x93\xfe9\xfe;\xfe\xb6\xfe\xa1\xff\xca\x00\xf4\x01\xee\x02\x8f\x03\xb3\x03B\x03M\x02\x07\x01\xab\xffa\xfeM\xfd\xb0\xfc\xd3\xfc\xc1\xfd\x15\xff.\x00\x9b\x00b\x00\xe6\xff\x8b\xffz\xff\xa3\xff\xe7\xff1\x00y\x00\xb5\x00\xd7\x00\xd7\x00\xb9\x00\x8e\x00g\x00K\x009\x001\x007\x00H\x00Y\x00^\x00W\x00M\x00I\x00I\x00G\x00C\x00I\x00]\x00w\x00\x8c\x00\x98\x00\xa6\x00\xb8\x00\xc2\x00\xb8\x00\x9f\x00\x89\x00~\x00w\x00g\x00I\x00&\x00\x06\x00\xed\xff\xda\xff\xcd\xff\xc6\xff\xc2\xff\xba\xff\xaf\xff\xa5\xff\xa5\xff\xab\xff\xad\xff\xa5\xff\x9b\xff\x9b\xff\xa7\xff\xb5\xff\xc0\xff\xca\xff\xd4\xff\xd7\xff\xcf\xff\xc8\xff\xcf\xff\xd8\xff\xd4\xff\xc7\xff\xcc\xff\xea\xff\xfd\xff\xe6\xff\xcf\xff\x1a\x00\xf4\x00\x0f\x02\xcf\x02\xd0\x02#\x02\x19\x01\xf6\xff\xe7\xfe\x1b\xfe\xd2\xfd'\xfe\xf5\xfe\xf9\xff\xfb\x00\xd8\x01m\x02\x91\x022\x02l\x01v\x00\x86\xff\xb9\xfe#\xfe\xd0\xfd\xc3\xfd\xf0\xfd?\xfe\x98\xfe\xe9\xfe'\xffX\xff\x89\xff\xc6\xff\x17\x00\x80\x00\xf8\x00p\x01\xc8\x01\xe0\x01\xa8\x01)\x01x\x00\xab\xff\xd8\xfe\x1f\xfe\xb0\xfd\xac\xfd\x18\xfe\xdc\xfe\xd8\xff\xeb\x00\xe9\x01\x99\x02\xcf\x02\x81\x02\xc9\x01\xcf\x00\xb7\xff\x9f\xfe\xb2\xfd \xfd\x0e\xfd\x80\xfdZ\xfeo\xff

how to convert this into .mp3 file ???

Comment: We have no idea where did you get this response from and how. You've got to be more specific.

Comment: I have get this response from live call stream. Response in the form of above i mentioned . but i need a response in form of .mp3 or .wav or text ? lot of confusions in my response ..i dont know what is the type of my response . could  you pls explain me what is my response format ??

Comment: please explain Adelin

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you just printed binary data in Python.

You could try to save it to binary file like this:

```
open('music.mp3','wb').write(x)
```

Where `x` is this data.

Comment: already i used this method .. its failed .. !!!!!!!! @AndriyMakukha

Comment: @shenbagapandian, well, it's unclear what you are asking. Show us the beginning of the data, or show us where do you get it from and how you get it, and then someone might help you.

Comment: **link**   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665147/how-to-change-my-response-into-wav-or-mp3-file
this is my question @Andriy Makukha

Answer (score 1):

The usually way to post here is to show the code that you've attempted (as well as the output), but for what it's worth:

When you say *convert*, do you mean that you opened up some other type of file (not MP3)?

It looks like you've read in binary data and printed it out as hex (that long string you posted is just a series of hexadecimal values).

If you're trying to *convert* from one filetype to another, you may want to look into the [**moviepy**](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/) module or directly call an external software that's build for this (like [**FFmpeg**](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) which is free).